# Sequence Prediction using keras LSTM

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I want to use LSTM for sequence prediction.
I am using keras for that.

Instead of predicting next word in a sentence, I want to predict label of a line.
In dataset, I have set of features and label associated with that line and bunch of documents which has set of lines.

Ex.
Documents : 200
Lines in each document(VAriable but max number of lines I do zero padding at the end to match the length): 400
Features associated with each line : 100

So my input feature size is : 200 * 400 * 100

Now each line has label associated with it which i want to predict. 
Possible values of label = 3

So my label size : 200*400*3

I am using following code for modeling the LSTM.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(400, 100)))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.01)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
```

I am getting some dimensional error which says:

Error when checking model target: expected activation_3 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (200L, 400L, 3L)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to predict a label for each line instead of one label for all lines you need to pass `return_sequences=True` to the `LSTM` layer. And then you need to wrap the following non-recurrent layers with the `TimeDistributed` wrapper so that they can correctly deal with the returned sequence data:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(400, 100), return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(3)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Activation('softmax')))
```